# Проводник не находит файл при его создании

Tags: android, файлы, запись

Изучаю язык Kotlin, узнал как записывать данные в файл, но не могу сам файл найти, то есть, вот код для записи в файл:

```
File(filesDir, "hello.txt").writeText("Hello World")
```

так я считываю файл:

```
val content = File(filesDir, "hello.txt").readText()
Log.v("file", content)
```

И в консоль я получаю свой текст, но в файловой системе(в провднике) а также в проэкте я не могу найти сам файл, что я делаю не так? И если файла нет, как программа может считывать данные?

Вот проект:
[image: это файловая структура проекта]

Вот код:
[image: код]

Вот результат выполнения:
[image: результат]

А вот сообщение о том что проводник не находит файл:
[image: сообщение]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Во-первых:** Приложение выполняется на Андроид-устройстве и файл создаётся там же. В ФС ПК (в том числе в проекте) его никак не может быть, даже если вы запускаете приложение в эмуляторе.
Для просмотра файлов Андроида в студии есть [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) - выведите в лог путь созданного файла и ищете по этому пути его там.

**Во-вторых:** `File(filesDir, "hello.txt")` - здесь вы указываете родительский каталог как `filesDir` (`Context.getFilesDir()`), который расположен в приватной директории вашего приложения и не виден никому, кроме самого приложения и вышеозначенного Device File Explorer (в случае debug-версии приложения).
Про варианты хранения данных на устройстве можно начать читать от сюда:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage